part of multidimensional array not accessible after assignment to different part
I have a 3 dimentional array. int maxStrLen, int numberColumns, int numberRows are all set to like big numbers, that cannot possibly result in out of bounds for input
char*** array = malloc(sizeof(char **)); 
for(int i = 0; i < numberColumns; i++) {
    array[i] =  malloc(sizeof(char*));  
    for(int j = 0; j < numberRows; j++) {
        array[i][j] = malloc(maxStrLen * sizeof(char));
    }
}

I have a copy string function that copies byte by byte
void copystr(char* pointer, char*** array, int length, int i, int j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < length; ++k) {
        array[i][j][k] = pointer[k+1];
    }
}

in the gdb... as soon as array[0][0][2] is set to something .
array[0][4][0] becomes in accessible. what is happening?
10            array[i][j][k] = pointer[k+1];
(gdb) print array[0][4][0]
$5 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) print k
$6 = 2
(gdb) n
9             for (int k = 0; k < length; ++k) {
(gdb) print array0][4][0]
Cannot access memory at address 0x555555646f54
(gdb) 
11

at first i used strcpy but then i thought because malloc is non-contiguous i'd just copy byte by byte. turns out it doesnt help.... and the setting of a byte as some space in the 3d array affects another space in the array... I have checked if the two positions are contiguous... they are not... so I really don't know what is happening

Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Hmmmm i don't know how it can get more minimal... because this is pretty much the problem...
I've changed the contextual names to just "array" if that's what you are talking about

Not more minimal, more reproducible. You haven't shown how you're calling copystr(), the values of the parameters, etc.

ohhh thanks very much. This is my 2nd question on Stackoverflow. I didn't know about this.
Anyways i answered my own question...

You're only allocating space for a sinlge pointer in array, but then you're using it as an array of numberColumns pointers, so running off the end of the allocated space, which results in undefined behavior.

Turns out this works
char ***array = malloc(numberColumns * sizeof(char **));  
for (int i = 0; i < numberColumns; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(numberRows * sizeof(char *));
    for (int j = 0; j < numberRows; j++) {
        array[i][j] = malloc(maxStrLen * sizeof(char));
    }
}

when you malloc each element?? im not sure why this works. perhaps its becuase each pointer is pointing to an array of pointers, so you can't just malloc space for the 1st pointer (which i thought you could). this makes sure that malloc allocates contiguous mem for each layer of pointer
